# ViewEncapsulation changes css styles specificity(weight)

Tags: css, angular

I have created a new Angular CLI project and a component where I have tried work on css specificity. Wherewer I tryed, class styles overwrite tag styles, but only on Angular project it's working vise versa

I have founded that ViewEncapsulation.None makes the css styles show darkgreen backgound-color and with the angular default view encapsulation (ViewEncapsulation.Emulated) browser shows aqua background-color.

component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";
//import {ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/cli/lib/config/schema";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-toastr',
  templateUrl: './toastr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toastr.component.css'],
  //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

html code

```
<div>
  <div class="myspan">
    something
  </div>
</div>
```

and styles

```
div div{
background-color: aqua;
}

.myspan {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

I expect to receive an answer why it works differently

Answer (score -1):

**FYI**

`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`: Any styles we define on a component don’t leak out to the rest of the application. But, the component still inherits global styles like twitter bootstrap.

`ViewEncapsulation.Native`: Styles we set on a component do not leak outside of the components scope. Component is also isolated from the global styles we’ve defined for our application.

`ViewEncapsulation.None`: We are not encapsulating anything, the style we defined in our component has leaked out and started affecting the other components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question related only to one component which doesn't have anything to inherite from the parent component, but anyway have different css behaviour with different encapsulation options. Could you please try it and help me with this question?